# React useState() with array default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use React useState to store an array of objects but I'm having a strange problem. The state will not take on the value I give it. I have tried all of the following:

```
const [items,setItems] = useState(props.items)

const [items,setItems] = useState([...props.items])

const clone = [...props.items]
const [items,setItems] = useState(clone)
```

but the value of items after each solution is an empty array. Even when `props.items` is not an empty array.

It works when I do for example

```
const demo = [{hello:'world'}]
const [items,setItems]=useState(demo)
```

Does anyone know the problem?

EDIT:

Concrete example:

This is the relevant part of the calling (parent) react functional element

```
const overviews = props.overviews.map((obj, index) => ({ ...obj, onClick: myOnClick}));
return <DragSort items={overviews}/>
```

then

```
const Dragsort = (props) => {
    const [ items, setItems ] = useState(props.items);
    console.log('dragsort 1:', props.items);
    console.log('dragsort 2:', items);
    console.log('dragsort 3:', props.items instanceof Array);
    console.log('dragsort 4:', items instanceof Array);
...
```

gives

[image]

Comment: can you supply a demo? also, by 'store', are you referring to redux?

Comment: I suspect that your `items` prop is being mutated somewhere else.  Are you modifying that somewhere else in the code?

Comment: @MattOestreich I mean 'store' in the general sense of the word. I'm not using redux.

Comment: @AlexW I don't think I'm modifying them. But it should still work if I clone it. A ```console.log``` after ```useState(...)``` for both ```props.items``` and ```items``` shows that the ```props.items``` is an array of size 1, for my test, and that ```items``` is an empty array.

Comment: @Dan makes sense, just wanted to clarify. I agree with Alex W - sounds like props.items doesn't exist when you're trying to use it. How are you passing `items` into your component? Does `items` come from an API somewhere?

Comment: @Dan depends how you are cloning, if you're using the spread operator you are only shallow copying.  I would recommend trying something like lodash with a deep copy method to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks you both, I have added a more concrete example as best as I could. In the meantime I will try to do a deep copy using lodash. It would be strange if that was causing a problem though, as the array elements are not very deep, and I don't see how it could cause a logical problem anyway.

Comment: Resolved. I'm dumb. The component had already rendered, so ```items``` was stuck. I had mistakenly believed that an update to the props in a parent would automatically propagate an update. Your comments helped me figure it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ensure that you are checking the result for the first time that the component is rendering. What may be happening is that you are looking at the result for the 2nd, or nth render, and at this point the state has already been set to a incorrect (in this case an empty array) value.